# UIButton problems with active

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to do this: when you press the button it changes the image (it is active), the data is wrote to the database. As the next time you load the button, set this button active or not?

Comment: Can you describe your question more clear?

Comment: @Leonid Minderoff: store in NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSUserDefaults *rememberDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

```
if ([[rememberDefault valueForKey:@"Autologin"] isEqualToString:@"Autologin_on"]) {
    btnAutoLogin.selected =NO;
}else {        
    btnAutoLogin.selected =YES;
}
```

In your Button Action Method :

-(IBAction)btnOnOffSwitch:(UIButton *)sender{

```
if (sender.selected) {
    sender.selected = NO;
}else {        
    sender.selected = YES;
}
```

}

and when you want to check use this:

NSUserDefaults *rememberDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if([[rememberDefault valueForKey:@"Autologin"] isEqualToString:@"Autologin_on"]){
        [self Login_pressed:@""];
    }